# How to find if value if not empty and not null in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How to find out if a field is not empty('') and not null in a pandas dataframe?

I am using `if not value and pd.notna(value):`

Is it correct or there is a better API which handles this logic directly?

Answer (score 2):

You could replace fields with empty strings or containing only blank spaces with `np.nan` or `None` in your dataframe and then use `notna` to find valid values.

```py
df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Moreover, `if not value and pd.notna(value)` does not work for an empty string or a field containing only blank spaces:

```py
value = ''
not value and pd.notna(value)  # this is True
value = None
not value and pd.notna(value)  # this is False
value = np.nan
not value and pd.notna(value)  # this is False
```

Answer (score 1):

How about changing empty value to NaN and then check. Kr.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [np.nan, 1, ""]})
df = df.replace('', np.nan)
print(df.isnull())
```

which returns:

```
       a
0   True
1  False
2   True
```

Alternative is to fill NaN by empty `''` then check:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [np.nan, 1, ""]})
df = df.fillna('')
print(df=='')
```

which returns:

```
       a
0   True
1  False
2   True
```